# Button is not aligning in center in bootstrap form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have made bootstrap contact from in which I want to align all its element in center.
Below is my code:

```css
    .third-section > form > input{

         width: 35%;
         margin: auto;
         margin-top: 25px; 
    }

    .third-section > form > textarea{
     
        width: 35%;
        margin:auto;
        margin-top: 20px; 
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <section class="third-section">
      
      <form>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required/>

          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required/>

          <textarea id="message" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"/>

      </form>

    </section>
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

As seen in screenshot button is not aligned in center.Someone please let me know how can I get desired layout. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following CSS

```
.third-section > form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you could provide a working jsfiddle with all of your code in it, that would help. However, from what I can see, your issue can be solved by putting all of your form inside of a container with the text-center class.

```
<div class="container text-center">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add bootstrap class 'text-center'. please refer the below code.

```
<section class="third-section text-center">
  <form>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required/>

      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required/>

      <textarea id="message" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"/>
  </form></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not aligned because the your button is actually an input. All the elements are centered because they have margin: auto (so the remaining space is split evenly between the two margins). But the input elements (and the elements with class btn from bootstrap) are inline-block, and margin left and right properties are not working on inline and inline-block elements.

One option is the one that metaDesign sugested. Another option is to explicitly set the display property of the button to `display: block`.

so something like:

```
input.btn {
  display:block;
}
```